# Add inventory value to low inventory level emails

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to add the product inventory value to the low inventory level notification emails in Woocommerce.

The email notification code is on [line 386 of WC_Emails class](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/67d899da3a3472bfaf1bf62505fbacb7bedf0908/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L386), however, it doesn't have an action so I'm not sure of the best way to add it without changing the core file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mail is just a function attached to a hook. You should be able to remove it and then add your own. 100% untested, so use at your own risk.

I'm not 100% sure on how to remove the callback from the `woocommerce_low_stock_notification` because I'm not certain how to access the `WC_Emails` instance.

```
function so_27786112_remove_notification(){
    $emails = WC_Emails::instance();
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_low_stock_notification', array( $emails, 'low_stock' ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'so_27786112_remove_notification' );
```

But as Andrew suggested you can just duplicate the `low_stock()` callback and modify it as you'd like. I've simply added a custom function to the appropriate hook. I've really only changed the `$message` equation to use the `get_stock_quantity()` method.

```
function so_27786112_stock_notification( $product ) {

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    $subject = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_subject_low_stock', sprintf( '[%s] %s', $blogname, __( 'Product low in stock', 'woocommerce' ) ), $product );

    $sku = ($product->sku) ? '(' . $product->sku . ') ' : '';

    if ( ! empty( $product->variation_id ) )
        $title = sprintf(__( 'Variation #%s of %s', 'woocommerce' ), $product->variation_id, get_the_title($product->id)) . ' ' . $sku;
    else
        $title = sprintf(__( 'Product #%s - %s', 'woocommerce' ), $product->id, get_the_title($product->id)) . ' ' . $sku;

    $qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $message = $title . sprintf( __( ' has %s remaining in stock.', $qty ) );

    //  CC, BCC, additional headers
    $headers = apply_filters('woocommerce_email_headers', '', 'low_stock', $product);

    // Attachments
    $attachments = apply_filters('woocommerce_email_attachments', array(), 'low_stock', $product);

    // Send the mail
    wp_mail( get_option('woocommerce_stock_email_recipient'), $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_low_stock_notification', 'so_27786112_stock_notification' );
```

If the first part didn't work, you should get 2 emails.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking. Had to change a few things in your code to get it to work but after that, you are indeed correct, it sends two emails now as the original callback wasn't removed.  I'll play around with it some more but if you or anyone else have any suggestions I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: What did you change? I'd like to update my answer if it would help other people. I did update the `remove_action` so see if that does any better.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking, that seems to work now.  As far as what I had to change, the `$message` variable is missing one ) at the end. But for some reason, `$product->get_stock_quantity()` did not work inside `sprintf` method, so I had to make that a separate variable ($quantity) and combine then combined `$title` and `$quantity` values in the `$message`. Hope that makes sense.  Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make your own class that extends the WC_Emails class.  Then copy the low_stock() method from their class into yours, which will override their function with yours.  That way you can adjust your own function however you want and you won't be editing the core file.

Another option would be to add the filters you would need there and submit a pull request back to WooThemes.  They may just accept it and make it part of the core.